# Firestore Paginate a query

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I took a look at this example https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors => `Paginate a query`, to paginate my data from firestore.

The data load works fine and I get my `.limit(3)` posts if I reached the bottom of the page.

But if I scroll again to the bottom the function runs again, that is great, but it's loads the same data, again, and does not load more posts from firestore.

Hopefully, someone can help me, thanks!

Code: `vuejs`

```
mounted() {
   this.loadMoreData();
},
methods: {
 loadMoreData(posts) {
    window.onscroll = async () => {
      let bottomOfWindow =
          document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight ===
          document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

       var vm = this;

       const db = firebase.firestore()

       function getMorePosts() {
          let first = db
            .collection("users")
            .doc(vm.userProfile.general.userId)
            .collection("posts")
            .orderBy("createdOn", "desc")
            .limit(3);

          return first.get().then(async documentSnapshots => {
            // Get the last visible document
            console.log(documentSnapshots);
            var lastVisible =
              documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
            console.log("last", lastVisible);

            // Construct a new query starting at this document,
            // get the next 3 posts.
            const next = db
              .collection("users")
              .doc(vm.userProfile.general.userId)
              .collection("posts")
              .orderBy("createdOn", "desc")
              .startAfter(lastVisible)
              .limit(3)
              .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                const allPosts = [];
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                  allPosts.push(doc.data());
                });
                // set data to vuex
                vm.$store.commit("posts/setProducts", allPosts);
              });
          });
        }

     if (bottomOfWindow) {
       getMorePosts();
       console.log("bottom");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you've shared the function `getMorePosts()` gets the first three posts and finds the last post. Then it queries the next 3 posts using the `last visible` document in the first query as the cursor.

The problem is the function always performs the same activity to fetch the first 3 posts and get the next 3 posts every time when you scroll to the bottom.

One way to solve this problem is to pass the last visible as a parameter to the function.
So initially the `last visible` document can be empty and then the query the posts and the query's `last visible` document can be passed as the parameter to load more posts and so on.

Hope that helps.